# How do I render an Archetypes in a template?

Tags: plone, archetypes

I would like to render a list of Plone Archetypes in custom template.

In my example, I'm searching 'PortletPage' type in the catalog and get 3 items.
Then I iterate on these items and i'd like to display them.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How much do you know about the templating engine used by Plone, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the documentation for Plone's TAL templating language as well as the portal_catalog tool.

Here's a quick example based on the issue you're describing:

```
<div tal:define="catalog context/portal_catalog;
                 results python:catalog.searchResults(portal_type='PortletPage');">

  <div tal:repeat="item results">
    <h3 tal:content="item/pretty_title_or_id" />
    <p tal:content="item/Description" />
  </div>

</div>
```